# Probability of a box of lightbulbs

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, gaussian-integers

I was wondering if anyone can check my logic here.
I'm given light bulbs that are used 24/7 and each light blubs will last on average 25 days. The light bulbs come in a pack of 12. 
The question is find the probability that the pack of light bulbs will last more than a year.

What I've done:

Given $N$ = sample size, which is 12. $\mu_{ind} = 25$

$\mu = N*\mu_{ind} = 12 * 25 = 300$

$\delta = \sqrt{N} * 25 = 86.60$

$z = (x-\mu)/\delta = (365 - 300)/86.60 = 0.7505$

using the z-table i got $0.2734$ then subtract that with $0.5$ because we want to find "more than" 365 days which gives me $0.2266$ or $22.66$%.

We're suppose to find the exponential distribution and find the central limit theorem but I did it this way. I was wondering if this apporach was correct.

Comment: Does the question mention anything about what distribution to follow?

Comment: Not really. Its just listed under "Central Limit Theorem"

Comment: Sorry I missed this part, their original distribution doesn't really matter since we are adding them, by the central limit theorem their sum approaches a normal distribution regardless of the original distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If the wait time between events follows an exponential distribution, then the count of events within an interval follows a Poison distribution.

Hint 2: A Poisson distribution is *approximately* Gaussian/Normal (some more so than others). (CLT)

Hint 3: A Poisson random variable is discrete over Integer-values.   Use Continuity Correction.  $$\mathsf P(Y\geq y)=\mathsf P(Y> y-\tfrac 12)$$

Hint 4: That looks like what you did.  So...

Comment: Ok thanks you. I just wanted to be sure. It felt simple so i thought I missed a step.